# What is the difference between "If you are lost" and "If you get lost"?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

> 1. If you are lost
> 2. If you get lost

I think "are" sounds stative and "get" sounds dynamic.

So what difference do they both actually make?

"If you are lost" can be a repeated or unchanging action - what would be the difference in that case?

Comment: I've [edit]ed your question to try to make what you are asking more clear. I included the text from the answer you posted because I think you meant for it to be part of your question. If it isn't quite right, it's OK to [edit] my changes.

Answer (score 2):

> If you are lost

This means that you currently are lost at this moment in time.

> If you get lost

This means if you end up lost at some point in the future.